# Stream API how to modify key and value in a map?

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream

I have a `String - Array` map that looks like this

> ```
> dishIdQuantityMap[43]=[Ljava.lang.String;@301d55ce
> dishIdQuantityMap[42]=[Ljava.lang.String;@72cb31c2
> dishIdQuantityMap[41]=[Ljava.lang.String;@1670799
> dishIdQuantityMap[40]=[Ljava.lang.String;@a5b3d21
> ```

What I need to do is

1. Create a new map, where key - only numbers extracted from String like this `( key -> key.replaceAll("\\D+","");`
2. Value - first value from array like this `value -> value[0];`
3. Filter an array so that only this paris left where `value > 0`

I've spent an hour trying to solve it myself, but fail with `.collect(Collectors.toMap());` method.

UPD:
The code I've done so far. I fail to filter the map.

```
HashMap<Long, Integer> myHashMap =  request.getParameterMap().entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> Integer.parseInt(e.getValue()[0]) > 0)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(MapEntry::getKey, MapEntry::getValue));
```

Comment: post the code of the stream that you've made so far.

Comment: @Maurice done, I've tried many different ways, but always fail with collectiing back to map.

Comment: @Mark_Daniels the first step `( key -> key.replaceAll("\\D+","");` is required to be implemented or map is already valid?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko is required :(

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko the request.getParameterMap returns the `String - Array` values showed in the code above.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: I've read this several times and still am uncertain what the OP wants.  Looks like the OP has an array of arrays instead of a map of arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using stream and an auxiliary KeyValuePair class.
The KeyValuePair would be as simple as:

```
public class KeyValuePair {

    public KeyValuePair(String key, int value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
    
    private String key;
    private int value;
    
    //getters and setters
}
```

Having this class you can use streams as bellow:

```
Map<String, Integer> resultMap = map.entrySet().stream()
            .map(entry -> new KeyValuePair(entry.getKey().replaceAll("Key", "k"), entry.getValue()[0]))
            .filter(kvp -> kvp.value > 0)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(KeyValuePair::getKey, KeyValuePair::getValue));
```

In the example I'm not replacing and filtering exactly by the conditions you need but, as you said you are having problems with the collector, you probably just have to adapt the code you currently have.

Comment: i think the array he mentions is of type `String` so `entry.getValue()[0]` needs to be parsed to Integer as well.

Comment: `KeyValuePair` could be implemented as a [`record`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Record.html) and it'll be only one line. But since you can create an instance of `Map.Entry` this class is **redundant**.

Answer (score 0):

I addressed this problem in the following order:

- **filter** out entries with `value[0] > 0`. This step is the last on your list, but with regards to performance, it's better to put this operation at the beginning of the pipeline. It might decrease the number of objects that have to be created during the execution of the `map()` operation;
- **update the entries**. I.e. replace every entry with a *new one*. Note, this step doesn't require creating a *custom class* to represent a *key-value pair*, [**AbstractMap.SimpleEntry**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html) has been with us for a while. And since **Java 9** instead of instantiating `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` we can make use of the static method [**`entry()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#entry(K,V)) of the `Map` interface;
- **collect** entries into the map.

```
    public static Map<Long, Integer> processMap(Map<String, String[]> source) {
        return source.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(entry -> Integer.parseInt(entry.getValue()[0]) > 0)
                .map(entry -> updateEntry(entry))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                          Map.Entry::getValue));
    }
```

```
    private static Map.Entry<Long, Integer> updateEntry(Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry) {
        return Map.entry(parseKey(entry.getKey()), parseValue(entry.getValue()));
    }
```

The logic for parsing *keys* and *values* was extracted into separate methods to make the code cleaner.

```
    private static Long parseKey(String key) {
        return Long.parseLong(key.replaceAll("\\D+",""));
    }
```

```
    private static Integer parseValue(String[] value) {
        return Integer.parseInt(value[0]);
    }
```

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(processMap(Map.of("48i;", new String[]{"1", "2", "3"},
                                            "129!;", new String[]{"9", "5", "9"})));
    }
```

**Output**

```
{48=1, 129=9}
```